# Find the next heading's tagname and index with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am looking for the next heading tagname and index with JavaScript/jQuery for each heading. For example, if the first heading was h1, and the second an h2, and the third an h1, and you did the function on the second h2, you would get tagname h1 and index 1 (0-based) because it's the second h1. Here's my code. It strangely always gives h2 as the tagname and 0 as index!

```
$("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6").each(function(index){
    var nexth = $(this.tagName.toLowerCase() + "~ h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")[0];
    var nexthtagname = nexth.tagName.toLowerCase();
    var nexthindex = $(nexthtagname).index(nexth);
    alert("Tag Name: " + nexthtagname + ", Index: " + nexthindex);
});
```

Here's some test html:

```
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p>Test</p>
<h2>Header 1.1</h2>
<p>Test</p>
<h3>Header 1.1.1</h3>
<p>Test</p>
<h3>Header 1.1.2</h3>
<h2>Header 1.2</h2>
<p>Test</p>
<h1>Header 2</h1>
<p>Test</p>
<h4>Header 2.0.0.1</h4>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have any test HTML?

Comment: Why do you want to get information for the *next* heading, instead of the current one? I'm missing some context of what you actually want to do

Comment: It's a long story. I need it to pass it to insertBefore in PHP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues is that your selector becomes `$("h2 ~ h1, h2 ...")` -- you want to actually use the element itself to get the next element type:

```
var nexth = $(this).nextAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6").first()[0];
```

From what I can tell, jQuery doesn't have a method for "next of type," but I could be wrong.  Using `$(this).next('h1, h2...')` will not work because that requires the very next sibling to be in that filter.  `nextAll` will look at all following siblings, but you only want the very next one (hence `first`).  Your indexing code appears correct.  See:

http://jsfiddle.net/wTubu/

Note that this will cause an error on the last element; you can just check to see if `.nextAll` has length, or if `nexth` is not undefined.

Comment: Why would $(this + "~ h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")[0].tagName.toLowerCase() not work?

Comment: @Agantacroxi because `this` cannot be converted to a string (at least not the string you would want)

Comment: You could also do `$(this).nextUntil("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6").next()` fyi

Comment: @Agantacroxi Good point; maybe it will work without the `.first`; not sure

Comment: @KevinB that doesn't work because the arrangement of hN/p nodes is not consistent: http://jsfiddle.net/wTubu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it so complicated. You already have a valid collection of headings in document order!

```
var headings = $("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6").get();
for (var i=0; i<headings.length-1; i++) {
    var cur = headings[i],
        next = headings[i+1];
     … // get tag name etc
}
```